# Grouping a Pandas Dataframe by two parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a .csv file of 8k+ rows which looks like this:

```
                       state                   assembly           candidate  \
0  Andaman & Nicobar Islands  Andaman & Nicobar Islands     BISHNU PADA RAY   
1  Andaman & Nicobar Islands  Andaman & Nicobar Islands  KULDEEP RAI SHARMA   
2  Andaman & Nicobar Islands  Andaman & Nicobar Islands      SANJAY MESHACK   
3  Andaman & Nicobar Islands  Andaman & Nicobar Islands        ANITA MONDAL   
4  Andaman & Nicobar Islands  Andaman & Nicobar Islands             K.G.DAS   

                                party  votes  
0              Bharatiya Janata Party  90969  
1            Indian National Congress  83157  
2                     Aam Aadmi Party   3737  
3        All India Trinamool Congress   2283  
4  Communist Party of India (Marxist)   1777
```

The end dataframe I wanted to get was one which contains all the states as rows and two columns - one which has votes received by a particular party (`"Bhartiya Janata Party"`, in this case) in that row's state and another which has the total votes from the state. Like this:

```
      State                Total Votes   BJP Votes
Andaman & Nicobar Islands       190328     90969.0
Andhra Pradesh                48358545   4091876.0
Arunachal Pradesh               596956    275344.0
Assam                         15085883   5507152.0
Bihar                         35885366  10543023.0
```

My code works but I'm pretty sure there's a much better way to get this done using fewer lines of code and without creating too many dataframes. Here's my code:

```
dff = df.groupby(['party'])[['votes']].agg('sum')
dff = dff.sort_values('votes')

BJP_df = df[df["party"]=="Bharatiya Janata Party"]
#print(BJP_df.head())

group = BJP_df.groupby(['state'])[['votes']].agg('sum')
state = df.groupby(['state'])[['votes']].agg('sum')

result = pd.concat([state, group], axis = 1, sort=False)
result.columns = ["Total Votes","BJP Votes"]
```

Any tips, suggestions, pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using **[`df.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)**:

Replace any other party except `Bharatiya Janata Party` as `Others` using [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and then use `pivot_table`, finally get [`sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) across `axis=1` for sum of votes.

```
df1=(df.assign(party=np.where(df.party.ne('Bharatiya Janata Party'),'Others',df.party)).
pivot_table(index='state',columns='party',values='votes',aggfunc='sum'))
```

---

Another method with [`crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) similar to `pivot_table`:

```
df1=pd.crosstab(df.state,np.where(df.party.ne('Bharatiya Janata Party'),'Others',df.party)
,df.votes,aggfunc='sum')
```

---

Finally, getting the Total and `reset_index()`:

```
df1=df1.assign(Total=df1.sum(axis=1)).reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1)
```

---

**Output:** (*Note: I had added dummy `Andhra Pradesh` rows for testing*)

```
                       state  Bharatiya Janata Party  Others   Total
0  Andaman & Nicobar Islands                   90969   90954  181923
1            Andhra Pradesh                      100      85     185
```

You can opt to delete the `Others` column later : `df1=df1.drop('Others',1)`

Comment: Almost thought this question was lost in the depths of Code Review. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Abhishek My pleasure. :) i started contributing to this community starting today. :)

Answer (score 2):

In all your code was not too bad. You can groupby on 2 items:

```
votes_per_state = df.groupby(["state", "party"])["votes"].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

> ```
> state Aam Aadmi Party All India Trinamool Congress    Bharatiya Janata Party  Communist Party of India (Marxist)  Indian National Congress    other
> Andaman & Nicobar Islands 3737    2283    90969   1777    83157   0
> Andhra Pradesh    0   0   85  0   0   100
> ```

Then you can define which party you're interested in, and manually assemble a DataFrame

```
party_of_interest = "Bharatiya Janata Party"
result = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        party_of_interest: votes_per_state[party_of_interest],
        "total": votes_per_state.sum(axis=1),
    }
)
```

> ```
> state Bharatiya Janata Party  total
> Andaman & Nicobar Islands 90969   181923
> Andhra Pradesh    85  185
> ```

If you want you can even add a percentage:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        party_of_interest: votes_per_state[party_of_interest],
        "total": votes_per_state.sum(axis=1),
        "pct": (
            votes_per_state[party_of_interest]
            / votes_per_state.sum(axis=1)
            * 100
        ).round(1),
    }
)
```

> ```
> state Bharatiya Janata Party  total   pct
> Andaman & Nicobar Islands 90969   181923  50.0
> Andhra Pradesh    85  185 45.9
> ```

Comment: I know that my code worked. I was just looking for something to improve efficiency as well as be more Pythonic. Seems like every project I work on ends up with me creating over 10-12 different dataframes. Don't know if that's just me. Thank you for your answer.